# Clicking on the email verification link gives a page that says 'Unauthorized'

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am facing an issue with my app which used to work perfectly.

I am using email authentication and verification in my app. The verification link gets sent perfectly but the issue is when I click the verification link. I get a blank white page with the word 'Unauthorized'.

[you can see it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnqFz.png)

After some testing, I found out that this error only happens on emails that end with kfupm.edu.sa ( which is the only domain I programmed my app to accept).

Is there anything I could do to solve this issue?

Comment: Looks like a firewall is blocking the firebase URL. Do you have Trend micro antivirus installed?

Comment: Nope, the weird part is that it suddenly happened, it used to work with no issues.

Comment: "suddenly" could mean that a software update to the firewall or security settings of your network might have changed by you or someone else. I'm saying this because firebase email verification URL doesn't start with the domain "trendmicro.com".

Comment: I see, I think firebase authentication got blocked by KFUPM servers for some reason. I will have to check them out. Thanks for your help.